# How do I pass a parameter argument from a ps.1 parameter to an identically named function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a diagnostic powershell script that I want server administrators to use with the following user flows:

- A Sysadmin pastes the script into a RDP/Remote Desktop window.  It executes immediately
- A Sysadmin runs the script from a command line, assuming the script policy allows it

I also want to have a diagnostic option to run in the following cases:

- A sysadmin runs a function with a parameter (-debug)
- A sysadmin runs a script with the function

This is simplified example

**Inspect-ProductionHost.ps1**

```
function Inspect-ProductionHost()
{ 
    param ([switch]$DoDebug)

    if($DoDebug -eq $True)
    {
        Get-DebugData 
        Write-output $DebugData
    }

    write-output "Testing Server"
    TestHost-Configuration1
}

cls #clear the output incase this is pasted in. Simplify diagnostics
Inspect-ProductionHost($DoDebug)
```

The problem is that when I execute this from the command line `.\Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug` the parameter does not flow to the function.

**Alternative explanation**

And I would like to run the script in these ways:

1. Paste code into RDP `Inspect-ProductionHost` and it runs without $DebugData
2. After the paste, type in `Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug`

-- OR --

3. Run the script from commandline `.\Inspect-ProductionHost`
4. Run the script from commandline `.\Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug`

Is this achievable in Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

Inspect-ProductionHost($DoDebug)

... is not how you'd use a switch. What you show in you later option is.

.\Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug

Also, for the switch, they way you are using it, this...

if($DoDebug -eq $True)

... is not really needed. It could be just this ...

if($DoDebug)

As for this...
"• A Sysadmin pastes the script into a RDP/Remote Desktop window. It executes immediately"

Unless this is being pasted into an PowerShell ConsoleHost instance, which has to be started after logging to the RDP target, then no, this will not happen.

With this effort, you are just pasting raw code into the ConsoleHost and running it when enter is pressed.  Pasting code, does not run code. An interactive keyboard action is still required.

You should really be copying the script to the RDP locatation and asking the admins to run it from the PowerShell host, vs this copy paste thing.
This way, you can get the run with or wihtout debug switch you are trying to use.

In this copy paste effort, which still requires that interactive step, for the debug thing to happen, you should make that a parameter a mandatory thing wth a boolean option.

So, it's your second option

3.Run the script from commandline .\Inspect-ProductionHost
4.Run the script from commandline .\Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug

... that is the most prudent way of doing this.

Eiter way, unless you have the PowerShell consolehost automatically start when logging into the RDP target, it has to be manually started and the code manually ran.

The other option, is to copy the script to the RDP target, use a logon script to fire it off, and have you script prompt for the debug run, that boolean response.

```
function Inspect-ProductionHost()
{ 
    param ([switch]$DoDebug)

    if($DoDebug -eq $True)
    {
        Get-DebugData 
        Write-output $DebugData
    }

    write-output "Testing Server"
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
}

Inspect-ProductionHost
Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        



Inspect-ProductionHost($DoDebug)
Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        



Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug
Get-DebugData : The term 'Get-DebugData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:7 char:9
+         Get-DebugData
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DebugData:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        








function Inspect-ProductionHost()
{ 
    param ([switch]$DoDebug)

    if($DoDebug)
    {
        Get-DebugData 
        Write-output $DebugData
    }

    write-output "Testing Server"
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
}

Inspect-ProductionHost
Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        



Inspect-ProductionHost($DoDebug)
Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        



Inspect-ProductionHost -DoDebug
Get-DebugData : The term 'Get-DebugData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:7 char:5
+     Get-DebugData
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DebugData:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0....       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0
```

If you really want to do this copy paste thing, which again, it just an odd thing to do, then this does not need to be a function. Just copy and paste the below into the consolehost this way.

```
param 
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('True','False')] 
    [string]$DoDebug
)

if($DoDebug -eq 'True')
{
    Get-DebugData 
    Write-output $DebugData
}

write-output "Testing Server"
Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
cmdlet  at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
DoDebug: false
Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        



param 
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('True','False')] 
    [string]$DoDebug
)

if($DoDebug -eq 'True')
{
    Get-DebugData 
    Write-output $DebugData
}

write-output "Testing Server"
Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
cmdlet  at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
DoDebug: true
Get-DebugData : The term 'Get-DebugData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:10 char:5
+     Get-DebugData
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DebugData:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Testing Server

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0        
WS01          WS01            10.0.0...       fe80::b812:f23d:94b3:33e9%4              32       0
```

Comment: We're pretty much on the same line of thought, and thank you for the optimization.  I did create a function to do the testing, then added IF logic at the end of the script outside of a function to allow for an Adhoc query.  The reason I'm doing this strange thing is because I need to support an instance where network connectivity failed and VMWare/iLO console access is he only way to diagnose or restore connectivity.  We're moving to TLS1.2 and don't want any server to become an island.